# How to cast a generic T type to a core data entity inside a view's body?

Tags: generics, swiftui

I have 3 core data entities: Car, Bus, Plane.

All these entities have a property called `title`.

I read one item of any of these entities and pass it to a view like this:

```
struct View3D<T:NSManagedObject>: View {
  // T can be Car, Bus or Plane from core data

  private var object:T

  init(_ object:T) {
    self.object = object
  }
```

at the body of this struct I will have something like

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    Text(object.title ?? "")
```

This will not compile because, obviously, `object` is of type `T<NSManagedObject>` and has no property called `title`.

I have to somehow cast `object` it to one of the core data entities, but how?

thanks

Comment: pass the title into the child `View`, not the object, then `body` will be called when the title changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> T can be Car, Bus or Plane from core data

No, according to your code `T` can be **any** class.

You need a protocol constrained to `NSManagedObject` and with a `title` requirement for example

```
protocol HasTitle where Self : NSManagedObject {
    var title : String { get }
}
```

In your three classes adopt `HasTitle` and declare the view

```
struct View3D<T:HasTitle>: View { ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I was suspecting that I would have to use a protocol there, but not sure how. SO is not letting me upvote you.

Comment: one question: you say all 3 core data entities have to adopt the protocol, but these entitles already have these properties. Will this cause a problem later?

Comment: Conforming to the protocol confirms at **compile time** that those classes have the properties. If you try to call `title` on a `NSManagedObject` instance which doesn't have the property you get a compiler error.

Comment: thanks again. [Another question for you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77312066/316469) if you are interested... 