# Case inside enum containing a function with a generic

Tags: swift

Continuing [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77311590/16916118)

Sorry about asking about generics involving protocols and enums but I am still learning this.

Like I said there I have 3 core data entities: Car, Bus, Plane.

All these entities have a property called `title`.

And I now have this view.

```
struct View3D<T:HasTitle>: 
  // T can be Car, Bus or Plane from core data

  private var object:T

  init(_ object:T) {
    self.object = object
  }
```

and this protocol, with the help of [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77311662/16916118)

```
protocol HasTitle where Self : NSManagedObject {
    var title : String { get }
}
```

on another class I have this enum

```
enum ViewChoiceList {
  case splash
  case anotherView
  case view3D(_ object:XXXXX)
}
```

when I use this I have this inside the body of a view

```
  case .view3D(let object):
    View3D(object)
```

View3D is mentioned at the beginning of this question.

See the XXXXX? What do I put there?

Ok, I can silence the compiler by declaring it like

```
enum ViewChoiceList<T:HasTitle>
```

but later I use this enum in things like

```
@Published var currentView:ViewChoiceList? 

private var stack:[ViewChoiceList] = [ViewChoiceList]() {
```

and I can figure out how to use these if I inject the generic in the enum.

Comment: XXXXX must be `HasTitle` as far as I can see.

Comment: I have the error HasTitle cannot conform to HasTitle protocol.

Comment: Where, your code snippets are far from complete? I don't get it in the enum.

Comment: The code I have here is huge and I tried to simplify. If you tell me what you don't get I add more code.

Comment: I was referring to the error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HasTitle` only has simple requirements like `title`, i.e. no associated type requirements or requirements involving `Self`, then `View3D` doesn't need to be generic. Just take in `any HasTitle` instead.

```
struct View3D: View { 
  private var object: any HasTitle

  init(_ object: any HasTitle) {
    self.object = object
  }

  var body: some View {
    // you can still use object.title here
  }
}
```

Then the enum can be:

```
enum ViewChoiceList {
  case splash
  case anotherView
  case view3D(_ object: any HasTitle)
}
```